# Events from another thread in C#

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I have a such code: http://pastie.org/1638879

I got it from someone's blog. It must sort big files.
I preform it in separated thread:

```
    protected virtual void goButton_Clicked (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    FileSort fileSort = new FileSort(fileNameEntry.Text, "./BigFileSorted.dat");
    fileSort.SplitProgressChanged += fileSortProgressSplitting; 
    fileSort.SortChunksProgressChanged += fileSortProgressSorting; 
    fileSort.MergeProgressChanged += fileSortProgressMerging; 

    Thread thread = new Thread(fileSort.Sort);
    thread.Start();
    //fileSort.Sort();
}

protected virtual void fileSortProgressSplitting(FileSort o, double progress)
{
    progressBar.Fraction = progress;
    progressBar.Text = "Splitting...";
}

protected virtual void fileSortProgressSorting(FileSort o, double progress)
{
    progressBar.Fraction = progress;
    progressBar.Text = "Sorting...";
}

protected virtual void fileSortProgressMerging(FileSort o, double progress)
{
    progressBar.Fraction = progress;
    progressBar.Text = "Merging...";

}
```

For small files everything is normally, but for big files(about 4 gb), progressBar stops on some value for some reason during the splitting step. But splitting was finished. What is reason of this stranges?
P.S. I'm writing it on Mono and Gtk#.

Comment: "I got it from someone's blog:" - hardly a stunning indictment!

Comment: Might want to look at the max size of an int, and the largest size of a single object in .NET...

Comment: That just catches the event. Where's the progress calculation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like winforms, Gtk has thread affinity. Your updates should happen on the main UI loop. You can do this via:

```
protected virtual void fileSortProgressMerging(FileSort o, double progress) {
    Gtk.Application.Invoke (delegate {
        progressBar.Fraction = progress;
        progressBar.Text = "Merging...";
    });    
}
```

See also the [mono Best Practices](http://www.mono-project.com/Best_Practices#Running_code_on_the_Gtk_main_loop_thread) notes on this.

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting. I've never seen GTK# before. So one can deduce from this that GTK can only have one GUI thread per process, right?

Comment: seriously what is it with mono people using old fashioned delegate syntax, read about lamba expressions. please

Answer (score 2):

You can't touch GUI objects from non-GUI thread. Results are unpredictable. Sometimes it will throw an exception, but not always.

Instead, use the `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` method (former is better). Like so:

```
protected virtual void fileSortProgressSplitting(FileSort o, double progress)
{
    BeginInvoke( new Action( () =>
        {
            progressBar.Fraction = progress;
            progressBar.Text = "Splitting...";
        } );
}
```

Comment: Oh... My bad. The argument still applies though, doesn't it?